# Unable to run multiple scripts in parallel

Tags: shell, unix

I am unable to execute 2 scripts in parallel through shell script.

I have 3 scripts: script1.sh, script2.sh and installpackages.sh.

My requirement is script1.sh and script2.sh have to run in parallel in the background and after completion of script1.sh and script2.sh, installpackages.sh should be executed.

```
selid1t601.xayybol.74> vi script.sh
exec script1.sh &
exec script2.sh &

installpackages.sh
```

can you please suggest how can i execute script1.sh and script2.sh in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already executing the scripts in background those are essentially running in parallel.  The only thing you need is to `wait` to ensure that the scripts have been executed before proceeding to the final step.  You need to say:

```
exec script1.sh &
exec script2.sh &
wait
installpackages.sh
```

From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html):

> wait
>
> ```
>    wait [jobspec or pid ...]
> ```
>
> Wait until the child process specified by each process ID *pid* or job
>   specification *jobspec* exits and return the exit status of the last
>   command waited for. If a job spec is given, all processes in the job
>   are waited for. If no arguments are given, all currently active child
>   processes are waited for, and the return status is zero. If neither
>   *jobspec* nor *pid* specifies an active child process of the shell, the
>   return status is 127.

Answer (score 1):

don't do `exec` in this case. this replaces the current process with the started program. just run them like

```
bash script1.sh &
bash script2.sh &
```

or

```
./script1.sh &
./script2.sh &
```

and put a `wait` behind as devnull said.

Comment: Using `exec` reduces the number of processes required. `./script1.sh &` first forks a new shell, then that shell forks a process for `script1.sh` to run in. `exec ./script1.sh &` forks a new shell, then that shell is *replaced* by the process for `script1.sh`.